# How can i run script, command on background and kill for request?

Tags: laravel

I would like run script with infiniti loop inside, all the time after server will restart. i created command eg.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Console\Commands;
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    class startParser extends Command
    {
        protected $signature = 'start:parser';
    }
?>
```

now i can run command: `php artisan start:parser` but is not in background.

Maybe i can use  `exec('nohup php artisan start:parser > /dev/null &');` or `Artisan::call('start:parser');` or Artisan::call('start:parser');
but how can i get ID of this process and kill script when required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not separate a command outside of PHP thread when doing `shell_exec()` or anything else.

If you want to run that command when server boots up and keep it running no matter what you should have a look at how Laravel is executing queue workers. This will give you idea of how to do that.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

With Supervisor you can have any command up and running all the time. It actually is capable of restarting a command if it crashes.

You can get PID then with `pgrep -f php` when `php` is filter to specific name. For example

`pgrep -f start:parser`